# show hide image inside div

Tags: jquery

```
    var hide = false;
    $(".list_rowtext").hover(function () {
        if (hide) clearTimeout(hide);
        $(this).children("img").fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        hide = setTimeout(function ()
        { $(this).children("img").fadeOut("slow") }, 250);
    });
```

`.list_rowtext` is a div tag. Actually what I want is that when I hover on div, image displays and when mouse focus removed then image disappears and this div tag is inside `listview itemtemplate`, means its repeating.
It is displaying image when I hover mouse on div but image didn't disappear when mouse focus is removed from that div.

Comment: can you provide your HTML code also

Comment: This may or may not be an issue - you're missing a semicolon at the end of `fadeOut()` - missing semicolons coupled with the use of `{` on a new line can cause hard to find bugs with JavaScript. You should add the `;` then and try it once again- it just might work this time.

Comment: adding a semicolon didnt help

Comment: <div class="list_rowtext"  style="width: 16%; text-align: left; padding-left: 5px;">
                                <a href="DisplayUnitsandLessons.aspx?id=<%#Eval("CourseId")%>"><span id="Name">
                                    <%#Eval("Name")%></span></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <img onclick="EditCourses(this);" width="16" id="im" height="16" border="0" style="vertical-align: middle; display:none;" alt=" " src="../../images/edit.png">
                            </div>                                       this div is inside itemtemplate tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A setTimeout-function is always executed in global scope, so **this** is **window** when the function gets executed.
Use a closure to point at the desired target:

```
    $(".list_rowtext").hover(
      function () {
        if (hide) clearTimeout(hide);
        $(this).children("img").fadeIn();
      },
      function () {
        var obj=this;  //closure
        hide = setTimeout(function ()
        { $(obj).children("img").fadeOut("slow"); }, 250);
      }
    );
```